# Best jQuery Carousel for Boootstrap?

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

We are working with Twitter Bootstrap in a new site.
For this site we need a Carousel that works with thumbnails and also that we can add html content (as Flash Movies).

Someone has a recommendation for us? Is there a recommended jQuery Carousel to extend the actual Bootstrap Carousel?

Thanks a lot of.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an awesome Pure CSS carousel; [this one](http://iamceege.com/pure-css3-content-slider/) here. If you really want to use jquery, I would say Bootstrap is fine for what you need - but you could also try this one [here](http://labs.juliendecaudin.com/barousel/). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Lachian, but none of these has thumbnails option... I need something like this one: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/